# JMS Serializer cannot serialize Entity with interface

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, fosrestbundle, jmsserializerbundle

I am trying to develop a Symfony2 API using the FOSRestBundle but I am stuck with an error regarding the serialization of one of my Doctrine entity (I'm using the JMS Serializer bundle for serialization).

The error message is the following : "**Resources are not supported in serialized data**"

The serialization worked until I made my entity implement a custom interface :

```
/**
 * Quotation
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="quotation")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Quotation implements FileStorageInterface
{
    // content
}
```

And the interface :

```
interface FileStorageInterface
{
    public function getFile();

    public function setFile($file);
}
```

I searched online but couldn't find anything about serializing an entity implementing an interface. So if anyone has an idea on how to solve this, I would gladly accept it.

Comment: Did I understand you right: if you drop string `implements FileStorageInterface` without any other manipulation everything is working fine?

Comment: That's exactly that !

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not specifically because you are implementing just any interface, but because the object's data contains a resource. Having a look at the interface in question, I suspect dat setFile() is being called with a resource as value and stored on a property of the object.

Comment: You're completly right, I store a stream inside the property of the object. But the thing is, I tried to exclude this property from being serialized/deserialized thanks to the @Exclude annotation of JMS but I still get the error.